# Conditional Probability in poker, Bayes Theorem

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes-theorem, poker

In a four person pokergame you are dealt a "king of heart" and "8 of spades". Three cards lay on the table none being a king or 8, meaning there is 41 cards left.

Q: What is the probability of the next community card is a king or 8th?

I hope this makes sense, English is not my first language.

Comment: Without loss of generality, the three cards on the table may as well have been the aces of spades, clubs, and hearts specifically.  It does not matter since whatever those three cards happened to be the resulting probability is still the same.  Now... the cards held by the other players are not visible and thus not relevant to you and may as well have still been mixed in the deck.  We have then each of the $47$ cards remaining are equally likely to be the next card... $6$ of which are kings or eights.

Comment: If you draw a ball at random from a bag with $47$ balls of which only six are red... what is the chance the ball you draw is a red ball?  I should hope that is an elementary enough problem you can answer.  The big thing to notice here is that the other players being present don't actually have any impact on the problem so long as they do not share any information about what cards they received.

Comment: Thank you so much, and with Bayes Theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as @JMoravitz commented, there is a much easier method.

However, since you desire to do so using Bayes' Rule:

---

The deck is partitioned into four parts: (A) the two *places* in your hand, (B) the three *places* face up, (C) the next *place* in the deck, and (D) the forty-six remaining *places* of the deck.

The cards are partitioned into three categories : (I) the king of hearts and eight of spades, (II) the six remainder of kings and eights, (III) the remaining forty-four cards.

The events are: $E$ the evidence, and $F$ the favored event.

The evidence is that the two places of $A$ contains both from the type-$\sf I$ cards, the three places of $B$ contains none from the type-$\sf II$ cards ... and therefore three from the type-$\sf III$ cards, with the remaining cards are split among the forty-seven places of $C$ and $D$ .   This is evaluated using multinomial coefficients as:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(E) ~&=~\left.\dbinom{2}{2,0,0}\dbinom{3}{0,0,3}\dbinom{1+46}{0,6,41}\middle/\dbinom{52}{2,6,44}\right.
\end{align}$$

The favoured event is that place $C$ contains 1 from the type-$\sf II$ cards ... with the remaining cards split among the 51 places of A, B, and D.

---

Well, that should suffice to get you started on finding $\mathsf P(F\mid E)$ using Bayes' Rule.